# ical RRULE Exception Date

Tags: icalendar

How can I specify an exception date in this weekly recurrence set (COUNT=18), e.g. no event on 20201222 and 202012229?

```
BEGIN:VEVENT 
CREATED:20191014T154353 
DTSTAMP:20191014T154353
DTSTART;TZID="CET":20201103T120000 
DTEND;TZID="CET":20201103T140000
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=18 
END:VEVENT
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [EXDATE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.5.1) property. Something like this:

```
EXDATE;VALUE=DATE:20201222,202012229
```